# BASH CUT associates with CD

Tags: bash, cut

i need some help here as i couldn't figure it out the errors.

```
read input    
echo -e "$input" | cut -c4-    
cd "$input" | cut -c4-
```

So I enter `cd test`, echo output is correct which is `test`.

I would like to change directory but it gives `cd cd test`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want should be:

```
cd $(echo -e "$input" | cut -c4-)
```

Which can be done as well like this (see bash "here strings")

```
cd $(cut -c4- <<<$input)
```